# how to solve two aar have same class?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

The two UserAction class in different aar have same package name and class name, but in practice they are different. The two aar both from third-party libraries 
 and I don't sure if they are same. When I build apk ,there is a error like this:

[image]

The two class show as below. How to modify this，or how can I at least exclude one jar in one aar?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'd guess you'll need just one of those libraries. But conflicting (transient) dependencies aren't unheard of. May not be solvable without repackaging. What aars bring those jars with them?

Comment: try gradle to exclude one. If not possible, try to supress the error.

`dontwarn **`

Comment: I have not got any jar naming as beacon_android_v2.8.1_official_cover.jar. You have intentionally created the jar and made a conflicting situation which contains same package location for UserAction class. If you check here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.altbeacon/android-beacon-library/2.8.1 there is no dependency also...